# How can I help my dog's furuncles?

Tags: dogs, medicines, diseases

I have a black colour Labrador dog, 2 years old. In the past 2 weeks, my dog has been suffering from furuncles in his paws ([interdigital furunculosis](http://www.merckmanuals.com/vet/integumentary_system/interdigital_furunculosis/overview_of_interdigital_furunculosis.html)). This starts with a redness of skin and becomes a big ulcer full of puss which burst after some days. What should I do for the cure of the furuncles? Please tell about the antiseptics and precautions which I should keep in my mind.

Comment: Has your dog been to a vet? Are all of the paws affected or just one?

Comment: No I didn't call to any vet till now.

Answer (score 3):

Interdigital furunculosis can have many causes, and the treatment will vary depending on what the cause of the cysts is.

Only your vet can diagnose the cause of the cysts and prescribe the correct treatment. I recommend calling your vet to schedule an appointment. The correct treatment will likely involve

- Caring for the wounds in your dog's paws
- Systemic antibiotic/antifungal therapy (i.e. medications given orally)
- (Extreme cases, or when a foreign body is present) surgery

**First Aid**

If your vet cannot see you immediately, it appears that you can use wet compresses (boil a cloth in a pot of water, pull it out, and **once it is cool** place it on the affected area for 10-15 minutes).

You can try to use triple antibiotic ointment (often called Neosporin in the US), but if any of the bacteria are resistant (becoming more common) then the ointment will make the infection worse. Mupircin is recommended in those cases, but it's only available through prescription in the US.

Comment: Dear zara thanks for your keen interest to answer my question. But I want to know the cause for the disease.  And what are the solid precaution to lessen the disease vigour.

Comment: @user3434 your vet will tell you what the cause is. There may be a foreign body (like a leaf or rock) stuck in his paws, or they could be irritated if he spends a lot of time standing on wire or concrete, or a lot of things. Your vet will know.